# Ajax jquery post, can't send a variable in my php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new in the Ajax's world, tho I've tried it maybe twice and it always worked like a charm. Now I am trying to send variable with ajax() method but it seems like I have 0 errors in my console but I think the problem is that I am sending no variable at all.. If, in my php file, I echo a string it's working. So my problem is that I can't echo out the variable. I am on Laravel 5, this is why you will see Request::get('my_input_name').

Here is my js code :

```
$('.select_blocs_check').click(function() {
    var blocID = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/send/getBlocHtml/",
        data: {id: blocID},
        success: function(html) {
            $('#preview-wrap').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my php file

```
    public function getBlocHtml()
{
    $bloc_id = Request::get('id');

    echo $bloc_id;
}
```

So, if I change my php file like this

```
    public function getBlocHtml()
{
    $bloc_id = Request::all();

    print_r($bloc_id);
}
```

Now, it will print out : array(). Like if I have nothing in my data.. What's wrong with my data parameter in $.ajax ?

Comment: try use data as object like a data: {id: blockID}

Comment: looking at http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html I don't see a `Request::get($key);` but I do see a [`Request::__get($key);`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method___get)

Comment: I've been using Request::get('name'); and it always worked perfectly. __get is working too but for this situation, the results is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I see Laravel 5 in your question. Try Request::input('id');  Which will pull both Post and get.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It won't let me comment on his question. Need 50 points. Just signed up.

Comment: Nothing happened, like if my data was empty.. So weird

Comment: Try return Request::all(); And see what your console says.  Laravel will send back a json object.

Comment: When I echo request::all(); it gives me an empty array

Comment: So check in Firefox, when you hit that JS, it will show the ajax request in the console.  I have more luck with Firefox, but chrome does it too.  The request will show you the values sent. So you can see if the JS variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change how you pass your data. Try this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/send/getBlocHtml/",
        data: {'id': blocID},    
        success: function(html) {
            $('#preview-wrap').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, since you send it as post, you should also get it using post method
$bloc_id = Request::post('id');

Answer (score 0):

try change `Request::get('value')` to `Input::get('value')`

API says

> This method is used for all request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE)

In Laravel 5 API is [Input](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get) static method. 
And [article](http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/) which may help to you.